# SQL LITE difference of 2 date time elements in same column

Tags: database, sqlite

I am new in SQL lite, I have a datetime column in this format:

| id | datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-26 19:08:49 |
| 2 | 2020-12-26 19:08:50 |
| 3 | 2020-12-26 19:08:51 |
| 4 | 2020-12-26 19:08:51 |
| 5 | 2020-12-26 19:09:07 |
| 6 | 2020-12-26 19:11:45 |
| 7 | 2020-12-26 19:52:49 |
| 8 | 2020-12-26 19:52:50 |

How can i compute the difference between the first element with the 2nd
the 3rd with 4th element  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window function `FIRST_VALUE()` to get the datetime of the the 1st row and with the function `strftime()` you can calculate the difference of each row:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT id,
         strftime('%s', datetime) - strftime('%s', FIRST_VALUE(datetime) OVER (ORDER BY id)) AS diff_in_secs
  FROM tablename
)
WHERE id > 1
```

Or with a self join:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       strftime('%s', t.datetime) - strftime('%s', m.datetime)
FROM tablename t
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY id LIMIT 1) m
ON m.id < t.id
```

I used `id` and `datetime` for the column names and `tablename` for the table's name, you can change them to the actual ones.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=f322e371c79fa4434e01372e099ac435).
Results:

```
> id | diff_in_secs
> -: | -----------:
>  2 |            1
>  3 |            2
>  4 |            2
>  5 |           18
>  6 |          176
>  7 |         2640
>  8 |         2641
```